# UPDATE-syntax not working with all columns

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm losing my mind over here.

I'm trying to implement a basic "Forgot your password?" functionality where the user inputs an email address to get a new password. Simple enough, right?

My problem is updating the database, replacing the old password with the new one.
I'm working with C# and MS Access.

Here is the update code:

```
public bool UpdateCustomer(Customer customer){
    try {
        if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        string sql = "UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET password=? WHERE userid=?;";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameters("password", customer.Password));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameters("userid", customer.UserId));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return true;

    }catch (Exception ex) {

    }finally {
        con.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The CUSTOMER-table consists of the following columns: `UserId`, `Name`, `Email`, `Password` and `CreatedDate`.

While debugging the try-catch throws an exception saying there is a syntax error in the UPDATE-statement. I've done a little trial-and-error replacing `password=?` with `name=?` just to see if it will update, and it does infact update the customer name!

The `Name` and `Password` columns are, as far as I can see, identical with the data type `Text`.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PASSWORD` is a [reserved word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/sql-reserved-words-HP001032249.aspx) in Access.

Try:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET [password]=? WHERE userid=?;
```

(Insert usual comments about storing passwords in plaintext being a *really* bad idea)

Comment: That was it! Thanks a million! I was going to try renaming the column, but since it's a big project someone else wrote years ago I wanted to keep that as a last resort. Thanks again!